# Text with "return" in it - Java scanner input

Tags: java, input, newline

This is my code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String speed_string = scan.nextLine(); 
String[] string_array = speed_string.split("\\s");
```

I want my code to handle newlines, such as copy-pasting two or more paragraphs into a single nextLine. Is that possible? As it is currently, it will take in whatever the input until the newline.

Comment: You need to be clearer about how you want your program to behave.  If you want it to input multiple lines, first you have to decide how you want the user to tell you when there's no more input.  Then you can use `nextLine` in a loop and use string concatenation to add newlines and add the strings together.

Comment: Then implements your own Reader.

Answer (score 0):

It will stop at the newline, as per the API states:

> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a
>   line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line
>   to skip if no line separators are present

So no, you cannot paste a big block and expect it to take it at once.

[See nextLine method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

Comment: Do you know of a way to input big blocks? Using other methods.

Comment: @user1614466 `Scanner` and file input methods will read one line at a time, so the only way to do it is put `nextLine()` in a loop.  Some OS's will let you paste a big block and they will act as if you had typed in multiple lines, but the user would still have to do something special to tell it there's no more.  To really allow cut-and-paste to input big blocks, you pretty much need a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the fact that `nextLine()` returns one line.  that's its whole purpose.  You can read two lines and combine those two strings, though.  Of course that means some knowledge of the file format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to do that using Scanner class because it can only read line confirmed by 'enter' or newline sign.
But you can also handle concatenating two lines using ArrayUtils.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String speed_string = scan.nextLine(); 
String speed_string1 = scan.nextLine();
String[] string_array = speed_string.split("\\s");
String[] string_array1 = speed_string.split("\\s");
String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(string_array , string_array1 );
```